# Expo Firebase invalid-app-credentials error intermittently

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm using Firebase with React Native Expo and trying to sign in using phone authentication. Everything works most of the time, but every once in a while i'll get the error invalid-app-credentials when trying to sign in. No accounts will be allowed to sign in because of this error for a few minutes to a few hours. Afterwards the error will go away and everything will work again. I'm unsure how to pinpoint where the error is coming from because it only happens intermittently. The phone auth quota is not being hit because not many people are using my app.

Here is the code I am working with. I have removed a lot of the unnecessary code that does not have to do with the phone authentication:

```
// other imports
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from "expo-firebase-recaptcha";
import { getApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  PhoneAuthProvider,
  signInWithCredential,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { db } from "../config/firebase";
import {
  collection,
  query,
  onSnapshot,
  where,
  setDoc,
  doc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/firestore";

// Firebase references
const app = getApp();
// console.log("app: ", app);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export const SignupScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  // Ref or state management hooks
  const recaptchaVerifier = React.useRef(null);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = React.useState();
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = React.useState();
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = React.useState();
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = React.useState(false);
  const verificationCodeRef = React.useRef(null);


// Declare the Timeout for Initial Page Load Fix
  const [isInit, setisInit] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      setisInit(true);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      setisInit(false);
    };
  }, []);

  // useEffect to check if component is still mounted before updating the state
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
    return () => setIsMounted(false);
  }, []);

  const confirmCode = async () => {
    let unsubscribe;
    try {
      const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId,
        verificationCode
      );
      await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
      if (isMounted) {
        setVerificationCode("");
        if (phoneNumber) {
          const q = query(
            collection(db, "redacted"),
            where("phoneNumber", "==", phoneNumber)
          );
          unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
            q,
            (snapshot) => {
              if (snapshot.docs.length === 0) {
                // add the user
              }
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log("signup error: ", error);
            }
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
        // error checking code
        alert("Unknown error occured. Please try again later.");
      }
    }

    return () => {
      if (unsubscribe) {
        unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {isInit && (
        <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
          ref={recaptchaVerifier}
          firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
          androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true}
          androidLayerType="software"
          attemptInvisibleVerification={true}
        />
      )}
      <View style={styles.top}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <Icon
            name="chevron-back"
            size={30}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Text>
        My number is
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{
            // style
        }}
        autoFocus
        autoCompleteType="tel"
        keyboardType="phone-pad"
        textContentType="telephoneNumber"
        onChangeText={setPhoneNumber}
      />
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[
            {
               // style code
            },
          ]}
          onPress={async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
              const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth);
              const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
                "+1" + phoneNumber,
                recaptchaVerifier.current
              );
              setVerificationId(verificationId);
              setTimeout(() => {
                verificationCodeRef.current.focus();
              }, 0);
            } catch (err) {
               // error checking
              } else {
                alert("Unknown error occured. Please try again later.");
              }
            } finally {
              setIsLoading(false);
            }
          }}
        >
            <Text>
              Enter Number
            </Text>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Text>
        My code is
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        autoFocus
        autoCompleteType="tel"
        keyboardType="phone-pad"
        textContentType="telephoneNumber"
        editable={!!verificationId}
        onChangeText={setVerificationCode}
        ref={verificationCodeRef}
      />
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[
            {
               // styling
            },
          ]}
          onPress={confirmCode}
        >
          <Text
          >
            Confirm Code
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SignupScreen;
```

Again the error only happens intermittently and can last from minutes to hours. I'm really not sure what to do next.

I have tried updating my app credentials, adding a authorized domain, and double checking to make sure the GoogleServices files are all correct.